# Hex to Ascii conversion problem

Tags: hex, ascii

What is the ascii representation of this hex value: 0x80487d2 every converter gives me a different answer, hopefully someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by ascii representation?

Comment: right, "0x80487d2" is an ascii representation :)

Comment: That's 3 1/2 bytes. Is that suppose do be packed 7-bit ascii or something?

Comment: How do i find the ascii characters that will give me that address in hex?

Comment: I think you mean decimal, not ascii.

Answer (score 3):

0x80487d2 has no ASCII representation.

ASCII can only have characters in the range 0 and 127 (inclusive).  The hex value 0x80487d2 is well above 127.

That hex value can be split into multiple bytes but the way this is done depends on whether the machine is little or big endian, and regardless, not all of those bytes have an ASCII representation.  You won't find 0xd2 on any ASCII character chart (http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is a literal number (i.e. not some weird or little-endian encoding) the decimal representation is 134514642.